# How to save UIImageView data in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, save

I'm trying to find another way of sending images back fourth over and over again in between `ViewControllers` without using `prepareForSegue`.  Is there a way to save my image that I loaded up in the `UIImageView` and then later load it up again when needed in a different `ViewController`?

I'm trying to create an app that builds an object using multiple images layering on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` stores the image in a cache, but it only works for images in your application bundle. If you want to load images in your documents directory, you should look into building your own cache to load them.